# Getting logstash "fingerprint" filter to source every field

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using the `fingerprint` filter in Logstash to create a *fingerprint* field that I set to `document_id` in the `elasticsearch` output.

Configuration is as follows:

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    method => "SHA1"
    key => "KEY"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
  }
}
```

This defaults to `source` being *message*, but how do I make it SHA1 the entire record and not just *message*?  Note, what fields a record has depends on the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no built-in possibility to achieve this with the fingerprint plugin. Even the *concatenate_sources* option doesn't recognize all fields and as your fields change you cannot set them manually as *source*.

However, you might consider using the ruby plugin to calculate an SHA1 hash regarding all of your fields. Following might do what you want.

```
filter { 
    ruby {
        init => "require 'digest/sha1'; require 'json'"
        code => "event['fingerprint'] = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest event.to_json"
    }
}
```

I've just tested it and I get suitable SHA1 hashes regarding all fields.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Since I just want to digest the whole thing, I changed `to_json` to `to_s` and got rid of `require 'json'`.

Answer (score 2):

to add to @hurb's solution, with Logstash 5.x due to breaking changes the following seems to be working:

```
ruby {
  init => "require 'digest/sha1'; require 'json'"
  code => "event.set('fingerprint', Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(event.to_json))"
}
```